# How to blend the surface with html5 canvas?

Tags: canvas, colors, drawimage, game-maker

I can simply blend the surface in GameMaker using these codes:

`//The colour with which to blend the surface.
draw_surface_ext(index, x, y, xscale, yscale, rot, colour, alpha);`

or set "**the Fade to a Color**" property,it will looks like this:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnhWG.png)

For now I want to do the same thing with html5 canvas,but I don't know where to start,is there any canvas api could do that?Please can any one help to me.

Comment: The CanvasRenderingContext2D API can do that. Best place to start is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D

Comment: @Blindman67 Thank you for your advice,maybe webGL is the solution for now.I also asked question at [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139916/how-to-blend-the-surface-with-html5-canvas)